# Tensorflow object detection API test error

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am currently trying to use models from Google, and testing object detection API, but I met with the error which stops me from processing. Here are my errors. Can anyone tell me how to solve this:

```
tf@tf:~/Downloads/user/huyanju/models/research$ python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/home/tf/Downloads/user/huyanju/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 17, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import anchor_generator_builder
  File "/home/tf/Downloads/user/huyanju/models/research/object_detection/builders/anchor_generator_builder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import anchor_generator_pb2
  File "/home/tf/Downloads/user/huyanju/models/research/object_detection/protos/anchor_generator_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import grid_anchor_generator_pb2 as object__detection_dot_protos_dot_grid__anchor__generator__pb2
  File "/home/tf/Downloads/user/huyanju/models/research/object_detection/protos/grid_anchor_generator_pb2.py", line 41, in <module>
    options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
tf@tf:~/Downloads/user/huyanju/models/research$
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with your code?

Comment: I follow the steps introduced in the official website :                                  ...........
You can test that you have correctly installed the Tensorflow Object Detection
API by running the following command:

python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py               and at this step, I met the above error.   Here is the link in Github  :https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#add-libraries-to-pythonpath